# Cloud SQL response "Error: Could not handle the request"

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-functions

My static website is hosting on CloudCDN. And use POST send data to Cloud Function. Then Cloud Function will write data to Cloud SQL. But it shows Error: Could not handle the request when I press submit.
Also my SQL only have private internet access. But I have enabled Serverless VPC access. And my VM in the same VPC is able to connect to CloudSQL

This is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="<cloudfunction_link>">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my python code in Cloud Function

```
import mysql.connector
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def handle_form_submission():
    # Connect to the Cloud SQL instance
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                                  host='<Cloud SQL ip>',
                                  database='myapp')

    # Parse the form data
    name = request.form['name']
    email = request.form['email']

    # Insert the form data into the database
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    data = (name, email)
    cursor.execute(insert_query, data)
    cnx.commit()

    # Close the database connection
    cursor.close()
    cnx.close()

    return 'Form data submitted successfully'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Are there any additional diagnostics available in Stackdriver Logging? What are the Cloud Function logs saying, please check them and share the error message of the logs. Also share your requirements.txt file or make sure you have installed all the dependencies required.

Comment: I found the solution. Just change <form method="post" action="<cloudfunction_link>"> to <form method="post" action="<cloudfunction_link>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Glad to hear that the issue is resolved, maybe you can post the same as an answer so other members who are facing this similar issue are helped out.